# Descargar MYSQL en mac

Tags: mysql, macos

lo que sucede esque he intentado de mil formas descargar mysql en mac, lei todos los pasos que me dan en la página de ellos, y nunca me pide contraseña, ni me la da por default (como lo dice en la página)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html
Alguien que haya instalado Mysql me podria ayudar? ya que cuando intento conectar mysql ya sea a xamp, wammp, phpmyadmin o incluso a worbench, no me lo permite porque el password siempre es incorrecto.

Añado que he intentado con la contraseña vacia, 123, 1234, root, y la contraseña del usuario en mac.

Comment: Para facilitarme la vida, lo que yo hice fue descargar XAMPP y usar el MySQL que viene allí. Así no tuve que instalar el servidor MySQL de la página oficial.

Comment: mira te: https://www.macports.org/

Comment: Pero por ejemplo, no me deja conectarme al servidor local phpMyadmin por esa razón, dice que no se puede conectar por mysql

Comment: Verificaste que los puertos que ocupan mysql estuvieran libres?

Comment: Recuerda que al instalar XAMPP te instala las aplicaciones pero no las inicia. Debes ir a la consola de XAMPP y levantar (iniciar) estas aplicaciones manualmente. Una vez hecho esto, podrás acceder a ellas. Por defecto, MySQL viene con contraseña vacía.

Comment: Voy a intentar solo con xampp, porque ni con la contraseña vacia me permite acceder :(

Comment: Las instalaciones sobre Mac no son tan sencillas como debieran ser, y tal como comenta @LuiggiMendoza, los más rápido es usar una instalación XAMPP, MAMP, o en su defecto, una máquina virtual con el servidor similar al que vas a usar en producción. Vas a ahorrar tiempo, dolores de cabeza y tardes desesperantes.

Comment: @OscarR. Tenés toda la razón, logré hacerlo perfectamente usando el Mysql que viene por defecto en XAMPP, te agradezco mucho buen hombre :)

Comment: Te recomiendo usar Ampps, a mi me va mejor que Xampp o Mamp

Answer (score 3):

Intenta con [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/), la verdad no se como es xamp en mac pero mamp es un versión especialmente para mac y personalmente nunca me ha presentado ningún tipo de problema.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo hacerlo directamente desde un gestor, te voy a dar todos los pasos

Instalate [brew](https://brew.sh/) (sinceramente es genial)

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

este es el comando.

despues usa

```
brew install mysql
```

cuando ya lo tengas solo es correrlo.

```
brew services run mysql
```

y usa un buen gestor de mysql, te recomiendo [SequelPro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) es gratuito y muy muy bueno.

cuentame si necesitas mas ayuda.